# Custom Default manytomany manager with a parameter

Tags: json, django, annotations, many-to-many, django-custom-manager

Following model allows me to handle translations in the database without adjusting code in order to add a language.

```
class NameString(models.Model)
    en = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    de = models.CharField(max_length=55)
```

Example use in model called **Item**:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(NameString)
```

I use a ReadOnlyModelViewSet to view through an api. Which returns the following json:

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": 3,
    }
]
```

I would like to replace the *id* value in *name* field of the json with the actual name in a given language. This is possible by annotating the queryset as for example:

```
name_field = 'name__{}'.format(self.language())
queryset = Item.objects.annotate(name_value=F(name_field))
```

If I use a serializer with a value *name_value*, I get the following json:

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name_value": 'cucumber',
    }
]
```

**My question is**: how do I write a manager that would handle the *items* ManyToMany field in the ItemList model so that it returns a queryset in a specified language?

```
class ItemList(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

So that I get a following json:

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item_list_1",
        "items" [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name_value": "cucumber"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name_value": "apple"
            }  
        ],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even more elegant solution!

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name_value')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out about a different functionality that solved my problem without the need of the manager. You can simply overwrite json field names in class view serializers with a serializer method field in the following way:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_name_value')

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = (
        "id",
        "name",
    )

def get_name_value(self, obj):
    return obj.name_value
```